# React router v4 rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am doing the SPA separate with Login Page, but I was unable to route to the login page, the address bar was changed after clicking the logout button, but it did not render any login page content.

Version:

- NPM -> 6.4.1
- React-Router -> 4
- create-react-app

File: index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(  
  <Router> 
    <Switch> 
      <Route path="/" component={Main} />  
      <Route path="/login" component={AuthenticateLoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Main -> index.js

```
const SmartCabinet = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/smartcabinet' component={SmartCabinetIndexPage} />
    <Route path='/smartcabinet/:number' component={SmartCabinetEditPage} />
  </Switch>
)

const User = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/user' component={UserIndexPage} />
    <Route path='/user/create' component={UserCreatePage} />
    <Route path='/user/:number' component={UserEditPage} />
  </Switch>
)

render() {   
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="ui menu">
            <div className="right menu">
              <NavLink className="item" exact to="/login">Log out</NavLink>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Grid columns='equal' relaxed={true}>
            <Grid.Column width='2'>
              <div className="sidenav">
                <ul className="header">
                  <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/materialrequest">Material Request</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/smartcabinet">Smart Cabinet</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/user">User</NavLink></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column>
              <div className="mainContent">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                  <Route path="/materialrequest" component={MaterialRequestIndexPage} />
                  <Route path="/smartcabinet" component={SmartCabinet} />
                  <Route path="/user" component={User} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are we to assume you've imported `BrowserRouter` as `Router`? Add `exact` to your `/login` and `/` Routes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Yes, I have imported the BrowserRouter as Router, after adding the exact to my /login and / in Routes in index.js, but I now I only can navigate to login page, unable to navigate materialrequest, smartcabinet, user, but the address was changed as well. not showing the content